# Convert JSON to case class with a nested objects using Scala/Play

Tags: json, scala, parsing, playframework

Say the JSON response I'm working with is formatted as follows:

```
[
    {
       "make": "Tesla",
       "model": "Model S",
       "year": 2017,
       "color": "red",
       "owner": "Bob",
       "max_speed": 200,
       "wheel_size": 30,
       "is_convertible": true,
       "license": "ABC123",
       "cost": 50000,
       "down_payment": 2500,
       "other_property_1": 1,
       "other_property_2": 2,
       "other_property_3": 3,
       "other_property_4": 4,
       "other_property_5": 5,
       "other_property_6": 6,
       "other_property_7": 7,
       "other_property_8": 8,
       "other_property_9": 9,
       "other_property_10": 10,
       "other_property_11": 11
    }
]
```

The JSON here is an array of car objects (just 1 for simplicity), and I am trying to convert this into a model using a JSON Reads converter. Let's say I have a Car case class to represent each object, and that class has has a nested FinancialInfo case class to split up the amount of attributes logically, so to avoid Scala's 22 parameter limit.

```
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
import play.api.libs.json._

case class Car(
    make: String,
    model: String,
    year: Int,
    color: String,
    owner: String,
    maxSpeed: Int,
    wheelSize: Int,
    isConvertible: Boolean,
    license: String,
    financialInfo: FinancialInfo, // nested case class to avoid 22 param limit
    otherProperty1: Int,
    otherProperty2: Int,
    otherProperty3: Int,
    otherProperty4: Int,
    otherProperty5: Int,
    otherProperty6: Int,
    otherProperty7: Int,
    otherProperty8: Int,
    otherProperty9: Int,
    otherProperty10: Int,
    otherProperty11: Int
)

object Car {
    implicit val reads: Reads[Car] = (
        (__ \ "make").read[String] and
        (__ \ "model").read[String] and
        (__ \ "year").read[Int] and
        (__ \ "color").read[String] and
        (__ \ "owner").read[String] and
        (__ \ "max_speed").read[Int] and
        (__ \ "wheel_size").read[Int] and
        (__ \ "is_convertible").read[Boolean] and
        (__ \ "license").read[String] and
        (__ \ "financialInfo").read[FinancialInfo] and
        (__ \ "other_property_1").read[Int] and
        (__ \ "other_property_2").read[Int] and
        (__ \ "other_property_3").read[Int] and
        (__ \ "other_property_4").read[Int] and
        (__ \ "other_property_5").read[Int] and
        (__ \ "other_property_6").read[Int] and
        (__ \ "other_property_7").read[Int] and
        (__ \ "other_property_8").read[Int] and
        (__ \ "other_property_9").read[Int] and
        (__ \ "other_property_10").read[Int] and
        (__ \ "other_property_11").read[Int]
    )(Car.apply _)
}

case class FinancialInfo(
   cost: BigDecimal,
   downPayment: BigDecimal
)

object FinancialInfo {
    implicit val reads: Reads[FinancialInfo] = (
        (__ \ "cost").read[BigDecimal] and
        (__ \ "down_payment").read[BigDecimal]
    )(FinancialInfo.apply _)
}
```

However, I'm guessing since there is no property in the JSON called `financialInfo`, it is not parsing it correctly. In my real application, I'm getting this error when I use `response.json.validate[List[Car]]`:

```
JsError(List(((0)/financialInfo,List(JsonValidationError(List(error.path.missing),WrappedArray())))))
```

To summarize, in the example, `cost` and `down_payment` are not contained in a nested object, even though for the Car case class I had to include a nested model called `financialInfo`. What is the best way to work around this error and make sure the values for `cost` and `down_payment` can be parsed? Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you post your complete Json and case class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Reads` can be combined and included into each other.

So, having:

```
implicit val fiReads: Reads[FinancialInfo] = (
  (JsPath \ "cost").read[BigDecimal] and
  (JsPath \ "down_payment").read[BigDecimal]
  )(FinancialInfo.apply _)
```

We can include it into the parent `Reads`:

```
implicit val carReads: Reads[Car] = (
  (JsPath \ "make").read[String] and
  (JsPath \ "model").read[String] and
  fiReads  // <--- HERE!
)(Car.apply _)
```

Now, with the following JSON:

```
private val json =
  """
    |[
    |    {
    |       "make": "Tesla",
    |       "model": "Model S",
    |       "cost": 50000,
    |       "down_payment": 2500
    |    },
    |    {
    |       "make": "Tesla",
    |       "model": "Model D",
    |       "cost": 30000,
    |       "down_payment": 1500
    |    }
    |]
  """.stripMargin

val parsedJsValue = Json.parse(json)
val parsed = Json.fromJson[List[Car]](parsedJsValue)

println(parsed)
```

It is parsed properly:

```
JsSuccess(List(Car(Tesla,Model S,FinancialInfo(50000,2500)), Car(Tesla,Model D,FinancialInfo(30000,1500))),)
```

p.s. The `Reads` in the original question do no need to be wrapped into different `object`s. Related implicit values would be better inside same scope, closer to where they are actually used.

Comment: Thanks! Your solution worked, I guess I was over-thinking it too much. Specifically, replacing `(__ \ "financialInfo").read[FinancialInfo]` with `FinancialInfo.reads` is what fixed my example